# Sum of digits in a string

Tags: python, string, sum, digits

if i just read my `sum_digits` function  here, it makes sense in my head but it seems to be producing wrong results. Any tip?

```
def is_a_digit(s):
''' (str) -> bool

Precondition: len(s) == 1

Return True iff s is a string containing a single digit character (between
'0' and '9' inclusive).

>>> is_a_digit('7')
True
>>> is_a_digit('b')
False
'''

return '0' <= s and s <= '9'

def sum_digits(digit):
    b = 0
    for a in digit:
        if is_a_digit(a) == True:
            b = int(a)
            b += 1

    return b
```

For the function `sum_digits`, if i input `sum_digits('hihello153john')`, it should produce `9`

Comment: and what do you get instead of 9?

Comment: it produces 4 because it takes the last number 3 and plus 1 to it, since you set back the value of b every time running the loop

Answer (score 29):

Notice that you can easily solve this problem using built-in functions. This is a more idiomatic and efficient solution:

```
def sum_digits(digit):
    return sum(int(x) for x in digit if x.isdigit())

print(sum_digits('hihello153john'))
=> 9
```

In particular, be aware that the `is_a_digit()` method already exists for string types, it's called [`isdigit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit).

And the whole loop in the `sum_digits()` function can be expressed more concisely using a generator expression as a parameter for the `sum()`  built-in function, as shown above.

Comment: @HaseeBMir of course if doesn't work... in ideone you need to explicitly print the result. There is nothing wrong with my implementation, it'll work in any real interpreter, you just forgot to add a `print()`. Kindly remove your downvote, the problem is with _your_ code, not mine.

Comment: @HaseeBMir you shouldn't test other people's code in ideone, use a real interpreter, otherwise you'll get incorrect results.

Comment: ideone is most accurate coding editor out there

Comment: You should write full code then for all compilers and interpreters.

Comment: @HaseeBMir why don't you take a look at all the other million Python answers that are in this site? if you have free time in your hands you can start adding a `print()` to literally all of them, because according to you they are "all wrong" and should work "on all compilers and interpreters" and "ideone is the most accurate editor" xD

Comment: Okay no worries i removed downvote now i use main compiled languages not interpreted so I think its fine for python language. Cheers

Answer (score 9):

You're resetting the value of `b` on each iteration, if `a` is a digit.

Perhaps you want:

```
b += int(a)
```

Instead of:

```
b = int(a)
b += 1
```

Comment: wow that works! could you explain why mine didnt work though?

Comment: The line `b = int(a)` sets the value of `b` to be the integer value of the digit character. Then you add one to it. In your example, the last digit is `3`, so you set `b` to `3` and then add `1`, getting `4`. Instead, you want to increment `b` by each digit's value.

Answer (score 5):

Another way of using built in functions, is using the [reduce](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) function:

```
>>> numeric = lambda x: int(x) if x.isdigit() else 0
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + numeric(y), 'hihello153john', 0)
9
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner

```
sum_digits = lambda x: sum(int(y) for y in x if y.isdigit())
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to propose a different solution using regx that covers two scenarios:

1.
Input = 'abcd45def05' 
Output = 45 + 05 = 50

```
import re
print(sum(int(x) for x in re.findall(r'[0-9]+', my_str)))
```

Notice the '+' for one or more occurrences

2.
Input = 'abcd45def05'
Output = 4 + 5 + 0 + 5 = 14

```
import re
print(sum(int(x) for x in re.findall(r'[0-9]', my_str)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it:

```
def digit_sum(n):
  new_n = str(n)
  sum = 0
  for i in new_n:
    sum += int(i)
  return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent for your code, using list comprehensions:

```
def sum_digits(your_string):
    return sum(int(x) for x in your_string if '0' <= x <= '9')
```

It will run faster then a "for" version, and saves a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

Just a variation to @oscar's answer, if we need the sum to be single digit,

```
def sum_digits(digit):
    s = sum(int(x) for x in str(digit) if x.isdigit())
    if len(str(s)) > 1:
        return sum_digits(s)
    else:
        return s
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#if string =he15ll15oo10
#sum of number =15+15+10=40

def sum_of_all_Number(s):
    num = 0
    sum = 0

    for i in s:
        if i.isdigit():
            num = num * 10 + int(i)
        else:
            sum = sum + num
            num = 0
    return sum+num

#if string =he15ll15oo10
#sum of digit=1+5+1+5+1+0=13

def sum_of_Digit(s):
    sum = 0

    for i in s:
        if i.isdigit():
             sum= sum + int(i)

    return sum

s = input("Enter any String ")

print("Sum of Number =", sum_of_all_Number(s))
print("Sum Of Digit =", sum_of_Digit(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

simply turn the input to integer by int(a) ---> using a.isdigit to make sure the input not None ('') ,
if the input none make it 0 and return sum of the inputs in a string simply

```
def sum_str(a, b):
    a = int(a) if a.isdigit() else 0
    b = int(b) if b.isdigit() else 0
    return f'{a+b}'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.