# Sum of digits in a string to take care of whole number

Tags: python, sum

Please don't mark this question as duplicate as I have already seen the other question[Sum of digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550034/sum-of-digits-in-a-string)

Well, I have a following code

```
string = "2x83u0x7u8i9lkueieueue8"

numeric = lambda x: int(x) if x.isdigit() else 0
print reduce(lambda x, y: x + numeric(y), string , 0)
```

The answer should be 2 + 83 + 0 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 8 = 117 and not 45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a regex:

```
import re

string = "2x83u0x7u8i9lkueieueue8"

print(sum(map(int, re.findall("\d+", string))))
```

`"\d+"` finds 1 or more digits, so we just map the resulting list of string digits to int and sum

Answer (score 0):

`reduce()` always operates on each item in an iterable individually. In this case, that means that the substring "83" is treated by your code as the integer 8 and the integer 3, not 83. You need to change your approach if you want to correctly handle multi-digit values.